# Image slider blocked by Tracking Protection in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I've recently rebuilt a website for a free lance client who wanted to add GA to his site.  This is first time I've used GA.  On one page I included a javascript image slider.  The slider is being blocked in all 5 major browsers.  In IE 11 Web Developer tools I get this message for every page on the site:

"SEC7114: A download in this page was blocked by Tracking Protection. http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"

I think this is a GA setting that can be changed, but I haven't been able to find it.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Your computer has something installed (in fact Tracking Protection seems to be an IE setting) that prevents the Google Analytics from being downloaded ( so that's like an adblocker but works against web analytics software if you want to protect your privacy). This has very little to do with Google Analytics.

Answer (score 0):

Disable tracking protection.

What is an "image slider"?